Anim player message displaying when playing timeline and animation not playing
When I press the play button on the Blender timeline I get the message "Anim player" pop up at the bottom of the screen. Also the animation does not seem play, the bar on the timeline moves although the animation doesn't play on screen. This appears to be a new issue and has not occurred before.
I am running Blender 4.0.2 and using the Cycles render engine for this project.
Below are some attached images of the scene, when rendered the image on the TV changes, when playing back in real time rendering nothing happens.


The popup is normal, but you haven't given any details or shown any images of what animation you're trying to play.

I have edited the original question to contain an image and more information

Your image shows that you're in Material Preview mode which uses Eevee rather than cycles so it's possible that the method you're using to show the TV image won't display in Eevee. Try switching to Rendered view (top-right orb on the top toolbar) and see if that works although it may be too slow to display properly in realtime.

Thank you, I didn't know that material preview mode uses EEVEE instead of cycles, by switching to rendered view the problem has now solved.

Material Preview uses Eevee for speed. Glad you're sorted!

I have solved the problem by switching to rendered view(this uses selected render engine to render) from material preview(this uses Eevee to render). The animation that was playing could only be rendered in cycles therefore making it look like nothing was happening when rendered using Eevee.

Thanks for adding an answer. I was about to suggest that you did that!
